# Replace portion of a string depending on the number of occurrence of a character

Tags: php, string

Replace portion of a string depending on the number of occurrence of a character

```
$string = "|sampletext1|sampletext2|sampletext3";
```

Replace the text on the third `|` which is `sampletext3`

```
$string = "|sampletext1|sampletext2|thereplacedtext";
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Telling us that "_This is not a duplicate_" does not make it unique.  Let us be the judge of that.  Might there be four or more substrings that are piped together while you only wish to target the 3rd?  This is important to identify.  We also want to see your coding efforts.  Your question is too light on details right now and it requires anyone who wishes to answer to make assumptions.

Comment: Sorry, I looked up for the answers of my problem having same questions but they want different results than mine. I just want to make that clear

Comment: David's answer might be right, but it might be wrong too.  It solves one case of your issue, but we don't know how your input data might vary, nor do we know how your desired result might change based on the input. (I didn't downvote, but I think the downvoter is justified in doing so.)

Comment: There are so many ways to do this.  Do you want a single regex call?  Do you want to explode on pipes then replace based on index then implode?  How are you deciding which one to replace?  Too Broad <-- see?  Can I find a duplicate to close this with?  Probably, but I'd like to understand your task before making a nomination.

Comment: Relevant Reading: [Parse pipe-separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16256354/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$variable  = '|sampletext1|sampletext2|sampletext3';
$varArr    = explode('|', $variable);
$varArr[2] = 'thereplacedtext'; // Replace the 2 with the index you want to replace.
$variable  = implode('|', $varArr);
var_dump($variable);
```

[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/1037504)

This works by first [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)ing your string on the delimiter (`|`), then setting the index you want on this new array (`$varArr`) to your new text to replace, and finally [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)ing it all back together.

Comment: Can you give some explanation please in your answer? What if I want to replace the text after the 2nd `|` ?

Comment: @Azis If that's your actual question, then you should edit your question instead of posting a comment on my answer. I'll update my answer though.

Comment: Im asking the right question. The number of occurence, let's say 2nd `|` and replace the portion of the string after it.

Comment: Your answer is working but I need to know how to do this if in case I want to change the 1st portion of the string after the first  `|` or the 2nd portion of the string after the 2nd `|`

Comment: @Azis please clarify your question via an Edit.  Right now, your question is vulnerable to being closed as **Too Broad** or **Unclear what you are asking**.